# Representation of 2 and 7 in 5211 binary code

Tags: binary

In 5211 binary code 2 is represented as 0011 and 7 is represented as 1100. My question is why can't we represent 2 as 0100 and 7 as 1011 in 5211 code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Image from [here](http://www.asic-world.com/digital/numbering3.html).

5211 is "reflective: -

- "9" is the 1's complement of "0",
- "8" is the complement of 1,
- 7 is the complement of "2" etc..

> *My question is why can't we represent 2 as 0100 and 7 as 1011 in 5211
> code?*

Well, that would work but that isn't how it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

This code is a 4-bit application code where the binary weights carry 5, 2, 1, 1 from left to right. Hence the 5211 code represents the decimal numbers from 0 to 9.

[image]

This is the table for it. "3" could have been "0110" in your thought way. But it doesn't work that way. It may be more accurate to look at this issue in terms of coding and decoding.